# Possible bug in Blade templating system with html special characters

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-blade, html-entities

I'm not necessarily sure about this but it seems there's something strange going on with umlauts, accented characters and such on Blade templates with Laravel 5.1.

I was banging my head on the wall with a string that ended in an ä-letter which I really, really couldn't get decoded with html_entity_decode no matter what I tried.

Here's what I had in my Blade template file as I was going mad:

```
{{ html_entity_decode('just-another-string-ä') }}
```

Now, when I render the template in a browser window I obviously get:

```
just-another-string-ä
```

But in the source I have the following:

```
just-another-string-&auml;auml;
```

Which in my understanding does not stand for the string that I had given in the blade template.

...several minutes pass by...

After a while I changed the string to:

```
just-another-string-ä-test
```

And as a source-code result I get:

```
just-another-string-&auml;-test
```

Which indeed is much easily decoded than the "almost-double-auml" I got with the first string. In addition to the final letter/word replace I also noticed that things work as expected when I enter a line break in the Blade template after the line.

```
{{ html_entity_decode('just-another-string-ä') }}
{{-- erase this comment --}}
```

And everything is in order in the source code:

```
just-another-string-&auml;
```

Have I completely missed something here or does this smell like a bug?

Comment: My suggestion is to go into the compiled views (`storage/framework/views` in L5, `app/storage/views` in L4) and see what PHP is generated from your Blade. The whole line break after the line thing is very odd, and viewing the raw produced PHP may help you see what's going on.

Comment: (In order to know which view to look at, it may be worth deleting all currently-compiled views first and then browsing to the URL that sets this off so as to regenerate your views, so you can be sure you have the right version. Alternatively, if you're using L5, run the command `php artisan view:clear` to clear out the compiled views.)

Comment: Hi Alex, here's what I get generated in the views after clearing them:
`<?php echo e(html_entity_decode('this-is-a-string-ä')); ?>`

And the corresponding blade template code is:
`{{ html_entity_decode('this-is-a-string-ä') }}`

Comment: That's the PHP output for the view where it goes wrong? Because if I run that in `artisan tinker` I get sensible output: `e(html_entity_decode('this-is-a-string-ä')) => "this-is-a-string-&auml;"`

Comment: Does indeed work with tinker..

Comment: Can you pastebin a complete `.blade.php` file that does not work correctly? I'll see if it works for me.

Comment: There's not much to it :)

[pastebin here.](http://pastebin.com/CYcYJnFu)

Comment: Using that as the entire content of a view renders it fine: in artisan tinker: `view('x')->render(); => "this-is-a-string-&auml;\n"` in browser: `this-is-a-string-ä` in view source: `this-is-a-string-&auml;` No crazy double encoding of the ä.

Comment: Ooh I've worked it out - you need to ensure your txt editor adds a newline to the bottom of files. Most will do this anyway, but I'm guessing you use Windows as fewer text editors will do this here. If you use sublime, use `"ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,` in your prefs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've found the problem, though not really much of a solution.

After looking into this I found that it's not a Blade issue. Neither is it PHP or Apache - it's your browser.

For example, just create yourself an HTML file with the following contents:

```
this-is-a-string-&auml;
```

For me (at least in Chrome, I haven't tested other browsers), this will produce the same issues as you are seeing. If you have no trailing newline, view source will break, but if you do have one, it's fine.

So the solution is simple, enable the "blank newline at end of file" setting in your text editor. You should really have this turned on anyway, for example diffs work a touch better with a blank line at the end of a file (they don't see a difference where there is none), which means, by extension, version control systems like Git handle them a bit better. And it doesn't really hurt to have this enabled that I've ever found.

I would imagine that this is almost certainly a known issue, but I haven't looked into Chrome issue tracker or anything. Feel free to do so though, if you do want to get to the bottom of it. I'd be interested to know :)

Comment: Thank you for your input! I think you're correct. I'm on Mac, but Sublime had newline at eof set to false so I've changed it. Another thing I noticed was that having `{{ html_entity_decode('just-a-string-ä') }}` compiles to `e(html_entity_decode('just-a-string-ä'))`. And in function e we have `return htmlentities()` which re-encodes the string.. So, the possible Chrome bug + misuse of blade tags resulted in this double-encoding-madness :D

Comment: Yeah I wondered about it being Blade/PHP related with double encoding but it's very much not. As I said in my answer, if you just have a plain HTML file with the same content (but no newline at the end) Chrome renders it incorrectly, which rules out Blade and PHP here.